# Dar um insert em uma tabela com informações de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber como inserir em uma tabela ids de duas outras tabelas.
Por exemplo,há 5 tabelas uma é aluno, que tem as seguintes informações:

```
+--------+------------+
| ID_ALU | nome       | 
+--------+------------+
|  1     | aluno 1    |
|  2     | aluno 2    |
+--------+------------+
```

turma tem as seguintes informações:

```
+--------+------------+
| ID_TUR | nome       | 
+--------+------------+
|  1     | Turma 1    |
|  2     | Turma 2    |
+--------+------------+
```

Na tabela materia tem as seguintes informações:

```
+--------+------------+
| ID_MAT |  nome      |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | Materia 1  |
| 2      | Materia 2  |
| 3      | Materia 3  |
+--------+------------+
```

A tabela aluno_turma que junto o aluno a turma fica:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| ID     | ID_ALU     | ID_TUR     |
+--------+------------+------------+
| 1      |  1         |  2         |
| 2      |  2         |  1         |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Na tabela, que faz a junção de materia com a turma fica:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| ID     | ID_TUR     | ID_MAT     |
+--------+------------+------------+
| 1      |  1         |  2         |
| 2      |  1         |  3         |
| 3      |  2         |  1         |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Agora quero que o SQL verifique qual turma está o aluno e vincule a matéria da turma. Exemplo

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| ID    | ID_ALU  | ID_MAT  |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 1     |  1      |  1      |
| 2     |  2      |  2      |
| 3     |  2      |  3      |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia remover a tabela aluno_turma e colocar uma coluna com o nome turma na tabela aluno

```
| id_alu | nome    | turma
| 1      | aluno 1 | 2
| 2      | aluno 2 | 1
```

depois coloque o seguinte sql

```
INSERT NOTA
SELECT
    AL.ID_ALU,
    M.ID_MAT
FROM
    aluno AS AL
    JOIN materia_turma AS MT ON AL.turma = MT.ID_TUR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer um select juntando todos os registros e tabelas que você vai precisar, seguindo o relacionamento, e em seguida fazer um `INSERT`. Exemplo:

```
INSERT aluno_materia
SELECT
    AT.ID_ALU,
    M.ID_MAT
FROM
    materia AS M
    JOIN materia_turma AS MT ON M.ID_MAT = MT.ID_MAT
    JOIN turma AS T ON MT.ID_TUR = T.ID_TUR
    JOIN aluno_turma AS AT ON AT.ID_TUR = T.ID_TUR;
```